# Long process in unload works in Firefox+Chrome but not IE11

Tags: jquery, salesforce

I am using Skuid with Salesforce and have the following code:

```
 $(window).on("beforeunload", function (e) {
        call_long_process_to_save_skuid();
 });
```

The call_long_process_to_save_skuid invokes a save operation that returns
successfully.

```
function call_long_process_to_save_skuid() {
    myModel.deleteRow(userRow);
    var savePromise = myModel.save();;
    console.log(savePromise.state()); //this prints 'pending'
    while(savePromise.state()=='pending'){
        console.log("waiting for save promise state to change to resolved");
    }
}
```

The data is saved when using Firefox and Chrome but not IE11.

Any pointers as to what can be done? Here is a reference to a similar issue:

[Skuid Question](https://community.skuid.com/skuid/topics/model-model-save-operation-doesnt-complete-on-beforeunload)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has a similar issue, I am answering my question. I ended up doing a synchronous Ajax call to delete the row on Salesforce bypassing Skuid as explained [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/104026/rest-api-post-method-with-jquery). The Ajax call was made in the beforeunload event in the javascript.